# How to calculate jaccard similarity between two rows in data frame

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

I have an excel file with records of students including 14 attributes (Shown below). I want to calculate the similarity between each pair of students.

[image]

First, I have to convert rows in a character array. then I have made a document-term matrix and calculate the distance between each pair. Then I subtract the distance from 1. But find the wrong similarity.

```
F360 <- read_excel("C:/Users/DreamWorld/F360.xlsx")
mydf=data.frame(F360$nursery,F360$higher,F360$internet,F360$romantic,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
td1=as.character(mydf[1,])
td2=as.character(mydf[2,])
d1=paste(td1[1],td1[2],td1[3],td1[4],sep = " ")
d2=paste(td2[1],td2[2],td2[3],td2[4],sep = " ")
myvector=c(d1,d2)
mycorpus=Corpus(VectorSource(myvector))
dtm=as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(mycorpus))
jdist=as.matrix(dist(dtm,method = "jaccard"))
jsim=1-jdist
```

I'm expecting similarity between each pair of the row in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

recently, I have found that Function `sum` will give me a number of common attributes.

```
Com=sum((td1==td2)==TRUE)
```

Next thing is to get the number of elements in both vectors, which are obviously 4.

```
len = length(td1)
```

Finally, we can find Jaccard similarity, which is an intersection over the union.

```
sim = com/len
```